# Mounting google storage bucket folder using gcsfuse

Tags: gcsfuse

I am not able to mount a specific folder inside the google storage bucket

On OS X, this program allows you to mount buckets using the mount command. (On Linux, only root can do this.)

```
mount -t gcsfuse -o rw,user my-bucket /path/to/mount/point
```

On both OS X and Linux, you can also add entries to your `/etc/fstab` file like the following:

```
my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user
```

Can somebody help me?

```
my-bucket:foldername /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user
```

This doesn't work for me

Comment: Where did you come up with the syntax `my-bucket:foldername`? Is that a widely used syntax for other file systems? (If so, do you mind linking to some examples?)

Answer (score 9):

Mounting a specific directory within a bucket isn't supported for use with `mount` and `fstab`, but if you run the `gcsfuse` command directly you can do this with the flag `--only-dir`:

```
gcsfuse --only-dir foldername/ my-bucket /mount/point
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `gcsfuse`, you can mount an specific directory of the google cloud bucket using the `only_dir` (for example `only_dir=/foldername/`) parameter in the `/etc/fstab` line.

```
my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user,key_file=/home/ubuntu/key-gcp-storage.json,only_dir=/foldername/
```

This works for me in Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

`gcfuse` allows you to mount a bucket subfolder with content, using the flags `--implicit-dirs` (takes care of the content recursively) and `--only-dir` (mounts only a subdirectory).

Be careful with the syntax. The command is:

```bash
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --only-dir <subdir-relative-to-bucket> <bucket> <mount_point>
```

For example, in the cloud I have a bucket with the root `my_bucket` and a subdir `my_bucket/sub_dir/sub_sub_dir` which I want to mount into the local dir `mount_dir`, then I do

```bash
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --only-dir sub_dir/sub_sub_dir my_bucket mount_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the folder was not created at the destination. I was trying to mount to specific path in bucket and in that bucket, I did create that path.

Creating that path resolved the issue..